# Can not get response from Retrofit 2

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

Using Retrofit cant understand where is the mistake. Just return nothing from enqueue. i.e. my Result and List is 0; The Json response is given

```
Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
MovieClient client = retrofit.create(MovieClient.class);

Call<Result> resultCall = client.getMoviesList();

List<Movie> resultFromApi = new ArrayList<>();

resultCall.enqueue(new Callback<Result>() {
  @Override
  public void onResponse(Call<Result> call, Response<Result> response) {
    resultFromApi.addAll(response.body().getResults());
  }

  @Override
  public void onFailure(Call<Result> call, Throwable t) {
    //callback.onDataNotAvailable();
    Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: error");
  }
});
```

**MovieClient.java**

```
@GET("movie/popular?api_key=my_key")
Call<Result>getMoviesList();
```

**Result.java**

```
@SerializedName("results")
@Expose
private List<Movie> results;

public List<Movie> getResults() {
    if (results == null) {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
    return results;
}
```

JSON Response from API provided

JSON response:

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: share your json response

Comment: did you follow complete  [tutorial](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/)?

Comment: do you have permission to the internet on manifest?

Comment: I suspect it something to do with your pojo class which cannot identify the Json
Are you sure the variables in your pojo class are named the same as the response?

Comment: what is the response of  response.body.getTotalPages()

Comment: show us your model Movie.java

Comment: Thanks, everyone. Resolved

Answer (score 0):

You Movie.java class must be like this

```
public class Movie {

@SerializedName("vote_count")
@Expose
private Integer voteCount;
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;
@SerializedName("video")
@Expose
private Boolean video;
@SerializedName("vote_average")
@Expose
private Double voteAverage;
@SerializedName("title")
@Expose
private String title;
@SerializedName("popularity")
@Expose
private Double popularity;
@SerializedName("poster_path")
@Expose
private String posterPath;
@SerializedName("original_language")
@Expose
private String originalLanguage;
@SerializedName("original_title")
@Expose
private String originalTitle;
@SerializedName("genre_ids")
@Expose
private List<Integer> genreIds = null;
@SerializedName("backdrop_path")
@Expose
private String backdropPath;
@SerializedName("adult")
@Expose
private Boolean adult;
@SerializedName("overview")
@Expose
private String overview;
@SerializedName("release_date")
@Expose
private String releaseDate;

public Integer getVoteCount() {
    return voteCount;
}

public void setVoteCount(Integer voteCount) {
    this.voteCount = voteCount;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Boolean getVideo() {
    return video;
}

public void setVideo(Boolean video) {
    this.video = video;
}

public Double getVoteAverage() {
    return voteAverage;
}

public void setVoteAverage(Double voteAverage) {
    this.voteAverage = voteAverage;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public Double getPopularity() {
    return popularity;
}

public void setPopularity(Double popularity) {
    this.popularity = popularity;
}

public String getPosterPath() {
    return posterPath;
}

public void setPosterPath(String posterPath) {
    this.posterPath = posterPath;
}

public String getOriginalLanguage() {
    return originalLanguage;
}

public void setOriginalLanguage(String originalLanguage) {
    this.originalLanguage = originalLanguage;
}

public String getOriginalTitle() {
    return originalTitle;
}

public void setOriginalTitle(String originalTitle) {
    this.originalTitle = originalTitle;
}

public List<Integer> getGenreIds() {
    return genreIds;
}

public void setGenreIds(List<Integer> genreIds) {
    this.genreIds = genreIds;
}

public String getBackdropPath() {
    return backdropPath;
}

public void setBackdropPath(String backdropPath) {
    this.backdropPath = backdropPath;
}

public Boolean getAdult() {
    return adult;
}

public void setAdult(Boolean adult) {
    this.adult = adult;
}

public String getOverview() {
    return overview;
}

public void setOverview(String overview) {
    this.overview = overview;
}

public String getReleaseDate() {
    return releaseDate;
}

public void setReleaseDate(String releaseDate) {
    this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
}
```

}